# Flutter vsCode : adding/removing breakpoint freezes my app when I have isolates running

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

At the start of my app I create 6 isolates. After I doing this if I breakpoint on the main code and add or remove a breakpoint then the app freezes, when I press run again (and I have to press it twice before it freezes, but sure if that means anything).

I'm working in vsCode, Version: 1.85.1 (Universal). When I run 'flutter doctor' I do see a version 1.83.1 as well as 1.85.1, not sure if that is normal.

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.3, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale en-NZ)

Here is my code to create the isolates

```
static Future<void> setupSurfaceIsolate(MapSurfaceProcessingData mapSurfaceProcessingData) async {
    int countOfIsolates = 6;  

    for (var i = 0; i < countOfIsolates; i++) {
      ReceivePort myReceivePort = ReceivePort();

      /// Spawn an isolate, passing my receivePort sendPort
      Isolate.spawn<SendPort>(calculateUsingIsolate, myReceivePort.sendPort);
      // get the isolate send port, this is used to establish the connection, so that I can get the sendPort
      Future<dynamic> futurePort = myReceivePort.first;
      futurePort.then((value) {
        mapSurfaceProcessingData.isolateMap.add(value);
      });
    }
}
```

I also see in the call stack that the isolate has a grey background color not the main thread. But not sure if this is important or not.

[image]